# how to print bold font when using f-string?

Tags: python, ansi-escape

for f-string, how to print bold font for either integer or string?

I came to this below website saying using "\033[1m" before and after string. Question is how to use it inside f-string and how to do it for integer values as well? Thanks

https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-print-in-bold-in-python

Comment: Its the same. Did you try it? What output did you see?

Comment: its no different `print(f"\033[1m{13}")`

Comment: The output is terminal-dependent. E.g. I dont think Windows CMD uses ASCII escape sequences, but that doesn't really change the solution

Comment: Python uses [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for syntax colouring in the terminal.  Use the required sequence *before* the required text and reset the sequence *after* the text.  Reset is `\033[0m`.

Comment: If on Windows, importing `colorama` then initialising will set the underlying Windows configuration appropriately, thus allowing colouring.  Not required for *nix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the same as the regular string
Try this:

```
name = 'Yacoub'
age = 23
print(f"This is \033[1mbold\033[0m and my name is \033[1m{name}\033[0m\nI am \033[1m{age}\033[0m years old")
```

Output:

This is **bold** and my name is **Yacoub**

I am **23** years old

Comment: he just add for integer as well

Answer (score 3):

did you try doing? :

```
a_string = "abc"
bolded_string = f"\033[1m{a_string}\033[0m"
print (bolder_string)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it works. The mistake I had were:  include double quotes and sue 1m for before and after. The way you did above was correct. And it is also same to either string and integer. Thanks Asav.

Comment: Sorry Asav, I should accept your answer as well. But Abulubad add the case of integer as well to make it more complete. Thanks Asav